# New instance of pipeline is triggered when first is running in case of hourly schedule Azure data factory v2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure-data-factory

We have pipeline scheduled to run every hour. Sometimes the pipeline takes more than an hour to complete.

Currently, another instance of the pipeline starts in the next one hour resulting in 2 instances of the pipeline running in parallel.

How do we avoid this? How to make the next schedule to wait until the prior schedule completes (like SQL Server job agent)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tumbling window trigger, you could set the [maxConcurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger#tumbling-window-trigger-type-properties) to 1.